# execution time of insert and retrieval operation in mysql

Tags: mysql, performance

which will take more execution  time insert operation or select operation if both are single query affecting  only one row.
for eg:

```
insert into example values('id','name','email')
```

or

```
select *from example where id='id';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all benchmarking, you need to keep in mind:

- It's not usually a simple matter, there are a large number of factors that can affect the figures.
- Some of these factors are the number of indexes, historical patterns of read/write, database tuning, disk layout, fragmentation and so forth.
- It rarely matter for small thing like a one-row operation, provided you have an intelligent setup (correct indexes and so on).
- The best way to tell, for a given setup, is to test.

In any case, this sort of question usually arises when you want to choose the fastest of two functionally identical choices.

In this case, there is *zero* crossover in functionality so I'm not sure what you will gain with this answer. If you want to insert information, use `insert`. If you want to extract it, use `select`.

It's not like you can use `select` (no matter *how* fast it may be) to insert data into your database (well, other than as part of `insert into ... select ...`).

Comment: actually i just asked this question out of curiosity as both affect only one row .

Comment: @Arun, my gut tells me that reads would be faster than writes simply because a write probably entails a read/modify/write action-group, but that's _not_ my answer. My answer is to test in your particular scenario, and make sure it's representative.